# UITextField accepting only one decimal point with max 3 digits before decimal point & max 2 digits after decimal point

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I want to restrict `UITextField` to accept only one decimal point.

Also maximum 3 digits are allowed before decimal point & maximum 2 digits allowed after decimal point.

Please note that minimum digits can be 1 and decimal cant be entered a first.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Give your text field a delegate and evaluate the contents either with `shouldChangeCharactersInRange:` or `textFieldShouldEndEditing:` depending on how you want to handle bad input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much all folks for helping. By referring those answers I framed below answer.

**EDIT**

*While textfields having e.g. 462. & user touches backspace results to 462 which ideally should result to 46*

```
    - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
    {
        NSString *strTextField = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    // restrict textfield from entering ./0 at first place
    if (strTextField.length > 0) {
        NSString *theCharacterAtIndex0 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [strTextField characterAtIndex:0]];
        if ([theCharacterAtIndex0 isEqualToString:@"."] || [theCharacterAtIndex0 isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
            return NO;
        }
    }
    //    NSLog(@"%@ , %@", textField.text, strTextField);

    // automatically add decimal point after 3 digits entered
    if (![textField.text containsString:@"."]) {
        if (strTextField.length == MAX_LENGTH_BeforeDecimal && ![strTextField containsString:@"."]) {
            strTextField = [strTextField stringByAppendingString:@"."];
            textField.text = strTextField;
            return NO;
        }
    }

    // when decimal is deleted
    if ([textField.text containsString:@"."]) {
        if (![strTextField containsString:@"."]) {
            int indeOfdecimal = (int)[textField.text rangeOfString:@"."].location;
            NSString *strBeforeDecimal = [textField.text substringToIndex:indeOfdecimal];
            textField.text = strBeforeDecimal;
        }
    }

    NSArray *separator = [strTextField componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
    // to restrict textfield to single decimal
    if([separator count] > 2 ) {
        return NO;
    }
    if([separator count] >= 2) {
        // restrict the max digits before & after decimal points
        NSString *sepStr0 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[separator objectAtIndex:0]];
        NSString *sepStr1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[separator objectAtIndex:1]];
        if ([sepStr0 length] > 3) {
            return NO;
        }
        if ([sepStr1 length] > 2) {
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code for the same scenario.

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string 
{
NSString *expression = @"^([0-9]*)(\\.([0-9]+)?)?$";

    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:expression options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
    NSUInteger noOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:newStr options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0,[newStr length])];

    if (noOfMatches==0)
    {
        return NO;
    }

NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
    if(range.length + range.location > textField.text.length)
    {
        return NO;
    }
    if ([newStr containsString:@"."])
    {
        return newLength <= 6;
    }
    return newLength <= 3;

    //  return YES;
}
```

As `.` is consider as one character. so total would be 6 characters. You can adjust the values in conditions.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can achieve it using **Swift** and **Regular Expressions**:

1. Set the text field's delegate. This can be done either in code or in IB.
2. To validate text as it is typed by the user you can add the code to your delegate that is similar to the following:

   ```
   // Number of digits that are allowed before decimal point
   let kMaximumIntegerDigits = 3
   // Number of digits that are allowed after decimal point
   let kMaximumFractionDigits = 2

   func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

   // The replacement string is empty when the user have removed some characters.
   if string.isEmpty == true { return true }

   // Get the current string the text field holds.
   let currentText = textField.text ?? ""

   // Check the limits.
   if (string.characters.count + currentText.characters.count) > 6 { return false }

   // Get the string we are expecting to obtain after the replacement.
   var resultingText = currentText
   resultingText.insertContentsOf(string.characters, at: currentText.startIndex.advancedBy(range.location))

   // Check the final string with the help of the regular expression.
   let regex = "^(?:(?:[0-9]{1,\(kMaximumIntegerDigits)}[.][0-9]{0,\(kMaximumFractionDigits)})|(?:[0-9]){1,\(kMaximumIntegerDigits)})$"
   let regexRange = resultingText.rangeOfString(regex, options: .RegularExpressionSearch)
   if regexRange == nil { return false }

   return true

   }
   ```
3. Finally, you should verify the resulting text when the user is trying to end an editing session. You can do it like this:

   ```
   func textFieldShouldEndEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    // Get the current input string.
    guard let currentText = textField.text else { return false }

    // Create the regular expression for the final check.
    let regex = "^(?:(?:[0-9]{1,\(kMaximumIntegerDigits)}[.][0-9]{1,\(kMaximumFractionDigits)})|(?:[0-9]){1,\(kMaximumIntegerDigits)})$"
    let regexRange = currentText.rangeOfString(regex, options: .RegularExpressionSearch)
    if regexRange == nil { 
    // Show an alert to the user with the message that explains what the input is expected...
    return false 
    }

    // Make additional clean-up and finalize the editing session.
    return true
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex code:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
   // Only allow one decimal point and 2 digits after it
   NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
   NSString *expression = @"^[0-9]{0,3}$*((\\.|,)[0-9]{0,2})?$";
   NSError *error = nil;
   NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:expression options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
   NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:newString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [newString length])];
   return numberOfMatches != 0;
   return YES;
 }
```

The regex used here is "^[0-9]{0,**3**}$*((\.|,)[0-9]{0,**2**})?$".

Here number 3 (first bold) denotes the characters before the decimal point and number 2(second bold) denotes the characters after the decimal point.

You can play with this regex and create rule based on your requirement.